# Button image inline with text

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a button that contains text and an image illustrating a click event.  I understand it is feasible to display an image as a background on the button.

CSS:

```
    .upperLeftButton {
        display: inline-block;
        background-image:url(Images/checkmark.png);
        height:50px;
        width:200px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<asp:Button ID="checkInButton" runat="server" Text="Check In"  OnClick="checkInButton_Click"/>
```

Is there any way to display the image and text side by side within the button?

Comment: Yes...use `background-position` but that will depend on the look you are going for...which we can't tell without the actual image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes...use `background-position` but that will depend on the look you are going for...which we can't tell without the actual image.

Quick demo...

```css
  .upperLeftButton {
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-25-25-7.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center left 25px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
  }
```

```html
<button class="upperLeftButton">Check</button>
```

Comment: that's exactly what I am after.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### Add an `img` tag inside the `button`

Because [the `button` element can contain inner HTML content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Notes), you may use an `img` tag as an alternative to setting a `background-image` in CSS.

```css
img {
  margin-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
button {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/30" alt="Place Holder" />
  My cool button
</button>
```

Comment: Down-voter, I won't hate; please leave a comment so I know what's wrong with this answer — SO is all about improvement. According to [SO Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote), "voting down a post signals … that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information." Can you explain?

Comment: Well, it did exactly answer the question and it was what I was looking for, so thank you gfullam.

Answer (score 0):

Add `padding-left: 30px` (or whatever width of checkmark.png is) and `background: url(images/checkmark.png) top left no-repeat`  to button CSS, so it will offset the text, but leave icon in left corner.

EDIT: also, must likely you should add padding-top: 10px (or so) as well, so text is centered vertically in middle to icon as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to redesign (even with simple paint) background and add 'blank' space for text and place it there with css.

```
.button{
background-image: url('http://community.avid.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Components.PostAttachments/00.00.53.19.51/WhiteBlack10801440x1080.png');
background-size: cover;
width: 200px;
height: 50px;
text-align: left;
padding-left: 32px;}
```

Like in fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/pp719t5n/

Black space is your image and white space background for your text.